# How to produce this brilliant effect?

Tags: education

[image: Image of Darkrai]

I can't seem to get how to produce this effect in which the light rays are passing through the render. Opacity and fill don't seem to do the work. 
And, I think the rough texture is the grain filter.

Please anyone help me to make this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: and also what kind of background is that? is it a forest or texture stock or something else? any guesses are appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit the image into your question with a link next to it? Otherwise the question becomes meaningless if the link goes down (also, deviantart contains some nsfw stuff so you'll get more responses if people don't have to click through)

Comment: It's all about painting and masking. There's nothing automated that's going to do that. You simply need to paint highlights correctly. Most likely the *Color Dodge* blending mode was used to increase the sense of light blow-outs.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're just trying to figure out how to make the glows, not the space background or the pokemon illustration. I grabbed a space image from google images for this explanation. Normally you would make your own image or find a stock image.

If you don't already know where to change layer modes, group layers or make new layers, it's all in the Layers palette. Here's an image.

[image: Layers Palette]

1. Draw a straight horizontal line with the brush tool. Or make rectangle shape.
2. Apply horizontal motion blur to it. Filter > Blur > Motion Blur.
3. Duplicate the line and distort it somehow but still keep it horizontal. I just scaled it up and cut off the top portion of it for a harder edge. You now have two layers. You can duplicate it as many times as you want, each time creating a new layer.
4. Now you can take all the lines and put them over your image. Set the layer mode to Overlay. This will give you a very weak glow.
5. Group the lines in a folder and from now on use that folder to move all the lines around.
6. Position the line group where you want it. Then duplicate the folder group and move it to a different place on the image. Do this over and over changing position, scale, rotation etc. You're trying to get all the duplicates to look different.
7. At this point your lines appear very faint. If you duplicate the folder groups again without moving them, the lines will become twice as bright. If you move the new duplicates just a little, some parts will be bright and some parts won't be.
8. (Not shown in image)If you want to add glows on top of all this, make a new layer. Use a very soft brush at a large scale. Click once and set the layer mode on that layer to Overlay. Duplicate the layer to make it brighter.

9 (Not shown in image) That grunge texture is another layer. You can make your own – which would be a whole other tutorial, or find a stock image. The grunge layer is like also set to different layer mode like Overlay or Multiply.

[image: Glow Tutorial. Step by step]